# Работа с памятью сторонней программы

Tags: c++

Мне нужно найти диапазон памяти конкретной программы (процесса) и прочитать/заменить данные. К примеру - заголовок окна. Натолкните, пожалуйста, на путь, как будет логичнее решить такое задание, дабы не выдумывать адских велосипедных механизмов. Как я понимаю, мне хорошо подойдет C++.

p.s. Чем-то похоже на работу трейнеров для игр, которые меняют параметры, например, здоровье.

Comment: Ну вообще система (это одно из главных ее предназначений), не должна допускать даже просмотра (тем более изменения) памяти других процессов. Пока приходит в голову - писать драйвер и работать  на 0 кольце - там можно ВСЁ.

Comment: Как-то слишком сложно выглядит. Думаю есть более простое решение, судя по разнообразности тех же трейнеров для игр. Они читают и заменяют память сторонних процессов без особых проблем.

Comment: @АлексейСаровский это однозначно может быть сделано из юзермода при наличии достаточных прав.

Comment: Чтение чужой памяти - ReadProcessMemory. Получение базового адреса чужого процесса - OpenProcess, но тут я вот не уверен...

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов в правах-то и загвоздка. Автор не указал, в какие процессы он хочет залезть. Может, там и системные есть? Не спорю, что к каким-то (пользовательским) приложениям доступ получить можно, а если к системным?

Comment: @АлексейСаровский И к системным можно, если от админа. И права - не загвоздка.

Comment: Данные вещи делают отладчики, уточните операционную систему.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов смотря что ведь нужно. Руссинович, издание 6, глава 5.

Comment: @АлексейСаровский Русинович-то зачем? Вполне понятно чем читать, но у меня есть сомнения относительно чужого базового адреса, но это в отладчике проверяется за 3 минуты.

Comment: Заголовок окна-то как раз не проблема, посылаете оконное сообщение и всё. Но вы уверены, что программа не вернёт его обратно через секунду? Если это production-код, просто не делайте так.